# roslaunch failed: cannot launch node

Tags: beagleboneblack, ros

I have downloaded and compiled some `Ros` nodes from [here](https://github.com/tuuzdu/crab_project) (just to have more info). I am trying to launch the five `ROS` nodes with parameters using a `launch`[file](http://codepaste.net/zx81rr) that is taken from that repo.

After executing `source catkin_ws/devel_isolated/setup.bash` and executing `roslaunch crab.launch`(the launch file from the link above) the next error appears:

```
root@beaglebone:~# roslaunch crab.launch 
... logging to /root/.ros/log/4f6332fe-dbe2-11e3-86a8-7ec70b079d59/roslaunch-beaglebone-2067.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://beaglebone:58881/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /clearance
 * /duration_ripple
 * /duration_tripod
 * /joint_lower_limit
 * /joint_upper_limit
 * /port_name
 * /robot_description
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /trapezoid_h
 * /trapezoid_high_radius
 * /trapezoid_low_radius

NODES
  /
    crab_body_kinematics (crab_body_kinematics/body_kinematics)
    crab_gait (crab_gait/gait_kinematics)
    crab_imu (crab_imu/imu_control)
    crab_leg_kinematics (crab_leg_kinematics/leg_ik_service)
    crab_maestro_controller (crab_maestro_controller/controller_sub)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [crab_leg_kinematics/leg_ik_service]: can't locate node [leg_ik_service] in package [crab_leg_kinematics]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [crab_maestro_controller/controller_sub]: can't locate node [controller_sub] in package [crab_maestro_controller]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [crab_body_kinematics/body_kinematics]: can't locate node [body_kinematics] in package [crab_body_kinematics]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [crab_gait/gait_kinematics]: can't locate node [gait_kinematics] in package [crab_gait]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [crab_imu/imu_control]: can't locate node [imu_control] in package [crab_imu]
```

I have reinstalled the packages as suggested in some other threats about similar problems.

I also have noticed that

1º- if I move all the `executables`of the nodes to the folder `src/<package>/`, I'm able to execute `roslaunch crab.launch`. But I don´t want to leave it like that, not proper way to work ;)

Additional info:

2º- If I execute, for example, `source devel_isolated/<package>/setup.bash`and then `roslaunch crab.launch`, the package which I have just `source`-d works and executes... (while the other still don't)

3º- So I have `source`-d all the `source devel_isolated/<package>/setup.bash` and try again: no one worked this time.

This leads to think that the problems are due to ROS variable enviroment: if I make an `export | grep ROS`after 2º, I can see that the package path appears in `$ROS_PATH`-s and the others are not there:

```
root@beaglebone:~# export | grep ROS
declare -x ROS_DISTRO="hydro"
declare -x ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros"
declare -x ROS_MASTER_URI="http://localhost:11311"
declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/root/catkin_ws/src/crab_msgs:/root/catkin_ws/src/joy:/root/catkin_ws
/src/ps3joy:/root/catkin_ws/src/xacro:/root/catkin_ws/src/roslint:/root/catkin_ws/src/kdl_parser:/root/catkin_ws
/src/urdf:/root/catkin_ws/src/urdf_parser_plugin:/root/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro
/stacks:/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share:/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/stacks"
declare -x ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros"
declare -x ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR="/root/catkin_ws/build_isolated/crab_msgs/test_results"

root@beaglebone:~# source catkin_ws/devel_isolated/crab_imu/setup.bash
declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/root/catkin_ws/src/crab_imu:/root/catkin_ws/src/crab_msgs:/root/catkin_ws
/src/joy:/root/catkin_ws/src/ps3joy:/root/catkin_ws/src/xacro:/root/catkin_ws/src/roslint:/root/catkin_ws       
/src/kdl_parser:/root/catkin_ws/src/urdf:/root/catkin_ws/src/urdf_parser_plugin:/root/catkin_ws/src:/opt   
/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks:/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share:/root/ros_catkin_ws
/install_isolated/stacks"
declare -x ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR="/root/catkin_ws/build_isolated/crab_imu/test_results"
```

Seems that 3º overwrites the `source` executed before..., meaning that in `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`does not appear all he packages as they should.

I also have tried to force `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`using `export`command, but it didn't work. So, I have to change more environment variables apart from that, but don't know which one...

So, I don't know if I diagnosis is correct and, if so, what should I do to correct this... Hope I have gathered enough info.

Thanks in advance!!

Iñigo

Answer (score 0):

set the executable bit for files. most probably you need to set executable permissions for files.

```
chmod +x filename.
```